# How to set Window Width/Window Centers with vtkImageActor (or vtkActor)?

Tags: vtk

I want to set Windows Width/ Windows Center value when use vtkImageActor/vtkActor. But I could not find the way to solve it. 
(If I use vtkActor2d, it's okay, but I don't want to use it)

Answer (score 1):

Attach a `vtkWindowLevelLookupTable` to your mapper.

Basic Example:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkWindowLevelLookupTable> myLookupTable = 
vtkSmartPointer<vtkWindowLevelLookupTable>::New();
```

double WindowWidth = myImageReader->GetOutput()->GetScalarRange()[1] -
                 myImageReader->GetOutput()->GetScalarRange()[0];
double WindowLevel = (myImageReader->GetOutput()->GetScalarRange()[1] +
                  myImageReader->GetOutput()->GetScalarRange()[0]) / 2.0;

myLookupTable->SetWindow(WindowWidth);
myLookupTable->SetLevel(WindowLevel);
myMapper->SetLookupTable(myLookupTable);

Comment: Hi Johnny I have always trouble with this. What is the windows width and level in this case? Thanks

Comment: It basically sets the window width to the maximum range of your image data and window level to the center. ww = max-min, wl = (max-min)/2.

Comment: Hey JohnnyQ, What can I do if I want to change WW/WC in specified area?